# Batch fold text files with bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, code-folding

I am having a hard time doing something quite simple. I have around 2000 .txt files which are composed of a single line of digits. I would like to fold the single line into one column with many rows, using the fold command and overwrite the original file with this new, folded version. My attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.txt ; do
  fold -w 1 $file > $file
done
```

Doesn't work. Help? Thanks.

Comment: To avoid the need to directly handle and clean-up temporary files, see `sponge` from the `moreutils` package, at [“In-place” editing of files](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, you are declaring the variable "i" but using "$file" which does not exist. Even if it did, the second problem is that bash reads "left to right". That means that it will first see ">$file", and will overwrite the file's contents. Therefore, if you were using the correct variables, you would have lost your data.

So, one error saved you from the other, you lucky, lucky fellow :)

Try something like:

```
for i in *.txt ; do fold -w 1 $i > sillytmpfile; mv sillytmpfile $i; done
```

Comment: In my defence I have killa flu. Will give it a go. Just out of curiosity. I have 18gb of txt files. Any way of doing it without a temp file? Thanks.

Comment: @RSoul The tmpfile is created once for every file and removed immediately, shouldn't cause you any problems. The only way to do it without a tmp file would be to redirect the folded output to another file: `for i in *.txt ; do fold -w 1 $i > $i".folded"; done`. That, however, will double the number of files and I would not recommend it.

Comment: Okay. All part of the learning curve. :)

Comment: You can optimize it if you choose the path for `sillytmpfile` to be on a ramdisk. On Linux this is usually `/tmp`, `/run/shm` maybe others, check with `mount | grep tmpfs`.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` might also be an option, it handles the temporary file issue internally:

```
for i in *.txt ; do
  sed  -i 's#.#&\n#g' $file
done
```

Comment: Interesting. I will one day get around to understanding sed. ;)

Comment: Still creates a tmp file though. And my *guess* is it will take slightly longer since it has a regex to evaluate and will search the entire line for it.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely slower, Try this with both `fold` and `sed`... `time printf '%sabcdef\n' {1..1000000}  |fold -w 1 >/dev/null` ... Also the **output is different** because of the way in which original newlines are handled.

Comment: @PeterO: Around 6 times slower by my measurements, but I do not get any difference in output.

Comment: Maybe it is a version issue. Here are my commands and results of `wc` line counts: ... ***fold*** *(GNU coreutils) 7.4* `printf '%sabcdef\n' {1..1000000} |fold -w 1 |wc -l # -> 11888896` ...  
*GNU* ***sed*** *version 4.2.1* `printf '%sabcdef\n' {1..1000000} |sed 's#.#&\n#g' |wc -l # -> 12888896`

Comment: Ah I see, `sed` includes newlines from input in output, I missed it before because my `diff` ignores whitespace. So `printf '%sabcdef\n' {1..1000000} | tr -d '\n' | sed 's#.#&\n#g' | wc -l # -> 11888896`. But as noted, `fold` is a better choice for the OP.